# Django ListView error: __init__() takes exactly 1 argument (2 given)

Tags: python, django, listview

My view:

```
class MediaList(ListView):
    template_name = "media_list.html"
    queryset = Media.objects.all()
    paginate_by = 2
    context_object_name = "files"
```

When I do this it gives error saying `__init__() takes exactly 1 argument (2 given)`.

Whats wrong in here?

Comment: The error is pretty specific. Your init function takes one argument, no more and no less, and you're giving it 2. Try giving it one instead.

Comment: Show your `urls.py`.

Comment: @QPaysTaxes that's not a very helpful comment. The first of those two arguments is `self`, which can be confusing for Python beginners. If the error is occurring deep in a traceback, the problem probably isn't on that line anyway.

Comment: @Alasdair Ah, I wasn't aware that self was considered a parameter. I'm a little rusty with my Python. My bad.

Comment: @QPaysTaxes ... where am I passing 2 arguement ?

Comment: what will be the solution ?

Comment: You need to *show your urls.py*, as you have been asked.

Comment: check your urls and see if you have any <parameter> by mistake